# Inserting a block to powershell using Json

Tags: json, powershell

I have Json data like this

```
{
  "Library": [
    {
      "LibraryName": "John's Library",      
      "Books": [
        {
          "BookId": "0000786",
          "BookName": "BookA",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to add one more book item to this json file via powershell to get an end result like

```
{
  "Library": [
    {
      "LibraryName": "John's Library",      
      "Books": [
        {
          "BookId": "0000786",
          "BookName": "BookA",
        },
        {
          "BookId": "0000788",
          "BookName": "BookB",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following snippet , but doesn't seem to add

```
$libraryFileContent = Get-Content $libraryFile
$libraryData = $ser.DeserializeObject($libraryFileContent)
$bookObject = (New-Object PSObject |
   Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty BookId '0000787' |
   Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty BookName 'BookB'    
)
$libraryData.Library[0].Books | Add-Member (ConvertTo-JSON $bookObject)
```

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those where you think it should be a lot more complicated than it is! Try this -

```
$json = @"
{
    "Library": [
    {
        "LibraryName": "John's Library",      
        "Books": [
        {
            "BookId": "0000786",
            "BookName": "BookA"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
"@ 

$x = $json | ConvertFrom-Json 
$books = [PSCustomObject]@{"BookId" = "000788"; "Bookname" = "bookB"} 
$x.Library[0].Books += $books 

$x | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

Which should give -

```
{
  "Library": [
    {
      "LibraryName": "John's Library",
      "Books": [
        {
          "BookId": "0000786",
          "BookName": "BookA"
        },
        {
          "BookId": "000788",
          "Bookname": "bookB"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```